# Orion PUB/SUB protocol

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

What is the protocol used in Orion PUB/SUB?

NATS for example uses something like this: http://nats.io/documentation/internals/nats-protocol/

How this mechanism work in Orion on the protocol level?

I guess some of the following mechanism are used: https://github.com/slact/nchan#subscriber-endpoint in order to push the message to the subscriber through HTTP connection that is held open. Which one exactly?

BR,

Drasko

Answer (score 1):

Well, Orion HTTP notifications were initially designed for server-to-server communications. In fact, they allow Orion to connect other components in the "data chain" of FIWARE, using Cygnus or other mechanisms.

For server to client notifications, one alternative is to use a Websocket gateway between Orion and a Web Client. That's something has been implemented many times.

What we are doing now is to add "native" Websocket channels, apart from HTTP, for Orion notifications. Those websocket channels could be used in Server-To-Server communications or in Server-Browser communications. That does not mean we are going to change NGSI, that means we are going to add another notification channel, and modify the API to enable developers to flag they want to use a Web socket channel.

Comment: I am arguing that server-server PUB/SUB communication over HTTP is inefficient and does not make much sense. I am also asking - which method of the ones I enumerated does Orion use for server push over HTTP

Comment: Regarding WS - it does not go over http API endpoint - you need ws://<endpoint>. I thought that NGSI **expicitly** demands REST?

Answer (score 0):

Orion NGSI API is REST, based in HTTP as application protocol (which is sequence is based in TCP/IP as transport/network protocol). Orion can also works in HTTPS mode, using the `-https` [CLI parameter](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/admin/cli/index.html) (as long siwth `-cert` and `-key`).

In the past, we supported NGSI API based on CoAP (which in sequence is based in UDP). However, that code is no longer mantained (although is still available [here](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/tree/develop/archive/proxyCoap)).

Finally, we are developing a websocket transport for NGSIv2 (the new version of the NGSI API in which we are working right now), but it is yet in a very early and experimental status.

Comment: I understand very well that HTTP REST NGSI is used. However - problem with HTTP connections is that they are unidirectional and data can not be pushed from the server to the clients. This is well known problem that has been bothered people that develop browser apps for years. How do we solve this problem?

Comment: Websocket (mentioned in the last paragraph) would be a solution to that problem. You  can monitor this issue at githbu about the progress of this (yet) experimental feature: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/1181

Comment: Yes, for browser. But not for inter-system PUB/SUB. And moreover - NGSI **explicitly** states only HTTP REST endpoint for PUB/SUB - are you going to change the spec to use WS? I have posted more detailed questin above, please elaborate on the questions I posted there.

Answer (score 0):

@fgalan,

to be precise NGSI specifies PUB/SUB over HTTP protocol, which is unusual and probably not efficient.

In order to be capable to push the message back to HTTP subscriber from the server side, you have to use several tricks:

- Long Polling
- Interval-polling
- EventSource
- HTTP multipart/mixed
- HTTP Chunked Transfer

These prevent closing of HTTP connection, so that the server can push the data to the subscriber once they are arrived (note that this does not prevent re-opening HTTP connection for every PUB/SUB you want to do from client side, which is also resorce-consuming). You can read more about this here: http://mrjoes.github.io/2013/06/21/python-realtime.html

This is exactly what I am asking - which one of these methods are you using in Orion, and can you please point me to the code.

Because of these problems with HTTP it is really unusual to use HTTP for PUB/SUB. There is no sucessful solution that does it (to my knowledge), and all others use some other specified protocol for RT messaging - RabbitMQ (AQMP), Redis, NATS, Kafka, MQTT - you need a protocol that is suitable for PUB/SUB if you want it to be efficient.

Speaking of this - did you ever benchmark your PUB/SUB queue against other solutions? I'd really like to see Orion in one of these analysis: http://bravenewgeek.com/dissecting-message-queues/, side by side with battlefield-proven SW for this purpose. I'd like to see the latencies and throughput...

I can see why WS are needed, but I do not see how re you going to align them with NGSI spec - your spec today demands PUB/SUB over HTTP (via REST call). Are you going to change the spec?

Best regards,

Drasko

Comment: To follow the "SOF style" I think this explanation should be moved to the question post above. Then, I can complete my answer based in the new question text.

Comment: I am not sure what I have to do for this... This SOF is really not the best choice for development forum (it is more like user list) - we need developers mailing list (Google Groups will do) and Gitter channel on your Github (or Freenode IRC).

Comment: Remember we also have http://ask.fiware.org for topics not so related with development.

Comment: In the end, which one Orion uses: Long Polling, Interval-polling, EventSource, HTTP multipart/mixed or HTTP Chunked Transfer? Where to see this in the code?

Comment: The code is open and can be found at https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion. Probably the most interesting part for you is the rest/ library.

Comment: @fgalan I know that the code is open. I just wanted to hear from developers where to look exactly in the code to find subscription push from the server via HTTP req that has been open. I also want to know how you keep the connection open and how exactly you send HTTP message from the server towards subscriber (Long Polling, Interval-polling, EventSource, HTTP multipart/mixed or HTTP Chunked Transfer). There is not much comments in the code, and it is diffcult to figure out without the maintainers help.

Comment: Let's continue discussion about the code at https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/2066